# Dropping an object from a plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity, projectile

I've done this before, but it's been a long time.

Using trigonometric functions, I've been asked to solve the following problem. However, I'm at a complete loss as to how to do it. I have 5 questions similar that I know I can figure out if given an example.

A plane moving at $180$ mi/hr comes down to a $300$ ft elevation, flying straight and level. It releases a package to be caught in a net on the ground. Neglecting air friction, what should the horizontal distance between the plane and the net be at the time of release?

Comment: You said ignoring air pressure, do you mean ignoring air resistance or buoyancy?

Comment: Yea, I meant to say air friction... Sorry

Answer (score 4):

First calculate how long it will fall until it hits the ground, then use that time and the fact that its horizontal velocity will remain constant to calculate how far it will travel horizontally.

Comment: Is it possible to solve using trigonometric functions? I believe that's what is being taught...

Comment: If the question is worded similar to [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/94227/maximizing-range-of-projectile]) then yes you would use trigonometrics.

Comment: The "this question" link commented above is dead.